# Interaction of coherent X-rays with matter

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

If we could irradiate a metal or a plasma with a coherent beam of hard X-rays, would the main effect be an ordered oscillation of the electrons like with a classical EM wave, or "compton-style" collisions?

Comment: You may find this (paywalled, unfortunately) reference useful: X-ray quantum optics, Adams et al., [_J. Mod. Opt._ **60** p. 2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/09500340.2012.752113)

Comment: Note that coherent x-ray sources are few and far between. The only way I know about to create them requires a nuclear explosion, but that may just be a statement of my ignorance. Are there less destructive terrestrial sources?

Comment: Also note that X-ray lasers were the centerpiece of the crazier part of Ronald Reagan's "Star Wars" program, where, theoretically, space-mounted X-Ray lasers were going to locate missiles at the point of launch and destroy them before they had a chance to leave Soviet airspace.  I'm unaware that there has been any further research into them since Star Wars was scaled back to the SDI system that is currently deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Phase-contrast imaging with x rays has been achieved at the [LCLS](http://lcls.slac.stanford.edu). This is used to probe extreme matter states, such as the ones created by a shock launched by high-intensity laser-pulses incident on metal slabs.

See [this](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1381234) or [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/OE.21.024647) for instance.

Comment: Ah! I had heard people were working on x-ray band FELs, but hadn't heard they'd been successful. Very cool.

Answer (score -1):

For example, When copper metal is irradiated with X-rays, some X-rays penetrate into metal and get absorbed. If the metal is thin, some X-rays come out from the other side with low intensity.

If the incident X-ray beam is at an angle to copper block, scattered X-rays can be detected. Depending upon angle of incidence, some back scattered X-rays are also expected.

Interestingly, if the incident X-ray energy is of higher energy than K X-ray energy of copper,  characteristic Cu X-rays are emitted from copper block along with back scattered X-rays.

Comment: This answer fails to address the "coherent" part of the question in any way.